# How to block the app opening in android 3.0?

Tags: android

Can any one please help to block the app opening from android 3.0. I used some of the codes below but this doesn't helped me. So can any one help me with some other solutions which would work better.

```
<compatible-screens>
    all small size screens
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    all normal size screens
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
</compatible-screens>

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:maxSdkVersion="10"/> 

<supports-screens
    android:xlargeScreens="false"
    android:largeScreens="false"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true" />
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the SDK version on load

```
int SDK_INT = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
```

and act accordingly.

Comment: Is it possible to make the app not to install from specified version i.e android 3.0.

Comment: I don't think so, although I think when you publish to the android market you can specify which versions it shows up for.